# Is it possible to turn selected properties/ columns of an NSManagedObject back to fault to optimise memory usage?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Currently, I have a note application, which I am using the following CoreData structure.

```
extension Note {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Note> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Note>(entityName: "Note")
    }

    @NSManaged public var heavy_body: String?
    @NSManaged public var lite_title: String?
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID?

}
```

---

### Only fetching lite_title column to preserve memory usage

When displaying hundred to thousands of Notes simultaneously in a `UICollectionView`, I only need to display `lite_title`. This is to minimised memory usage. Here's the code to achieve such objective.

The following code, will only load all Notes' `lite_title` into memory, but NOT `heavy_body`.

```
private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Note> = {
    
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()
    
    // We will NOT fetch "heavy_body" explicitly during app start, because it is a heavy resource.
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [
        "lite_title"
    ]
    
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "lite_title", ascending: false)
    ]
    
    // Create a fetched results controller and set its fetch request, context, and delegate.
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.persistentContainer.viewContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil
    )
    
    controller.delegate = self
    
    return controller
}()
```

---

### Attempt to fetch heavy_body for 1 note, then hopefully able to discard heavy_body from memory

During 1 note editing, this is what I finish to achieve

1. Attempt to read `lite_title` will not trigger SQLite DB operation, because `lite_title` is already in the memory
2. Attempt to read `heavy_body` will trigger SQLite DB operation, because `heavy_body` is not yet fetched into the memory due to exclusion from `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch`
3. In order to remove `heavy_body` from the memory, call `note.managedObjectContext?.refresh(note, mergeChanges: false)` to turn it into fault. Hopefully couple with `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch` information, CoreData is smart enough to figure out, it only need to "fault" `heavy_body`, but leave `lite_title` untouched.

We write the following code in order to achieve the above goals

```
@IBAction func readData(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections else { return }
    
    guard let note = sections[0].objects?[0] as? Note else { return }
    
    if note.isFault {
        print(">>>> This is a fault.\n")
    } else {
        print(">>>> This is NOT a fault.\n")
    }
    
    print(">>>> Read lite_title\n")
    
    let lite_title = note.lite_title
    
    print(">>>> After accessing lite_title, isFault is \(note.isFault)\n")
    
    print(">>>> Read heavy_body\n")
    
    let heavy_body = note.heavy_body
    
    print(">>>> After accessing heavy_body, isFault is \(note.isFault)\n")
    
    // Move the object back to fault.
    note.managedObjectContext?.refresh(note, mergeChanges: false)
    
    print(">>>> After moving object back to fault, isFault is \(note.isFault)\n")
}
```

---

### 1st Attempt seems to work as expected

Our 1st execution seems to work as expected. We get the following logging

```
>>>> This is a fault.

>>>> Read lite_title

>>>> After accessing lite_title, isFault is true

>>>> Read heavy_body

CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZHEAVY_BODY, t0.ZLITE_TITLE, t0.ZUUID FROM ZNOTE t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)1
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x600002151040> on entity 'Note' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZHEAVY_BODY, t0.ZLITE_TITLE, t0.ZUUID FROM ZNOTE t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? ' returned 1 rows
CoreData: annotation:  with values: (
    "<NSSQLRow: 0x600000c00b40>{Note 1-1-5 heavy_body=\"the body, which is a heavy resource\" lite_title=\"the title\" uuid=F80CE382-0345-49A0-AD34-2BAF317AB0C0 and to-manys=0x0}"
)
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0006s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0xbee59927ca0b4c5b <x-coredata://DBF3953E-6ABA-4542-9F79-89822F537A93/Note/p1> with row values: <NSSQLRow: 0x600000c00b40>{Note 1-1-5 heavy_body="the body, which is a heavy resource" lite_title="the title" uuid=F80CE382-0345-49A0-AD34-2BAF317AB0C0 and to-manys=0x0}
>>>> After accessing heavy_body, isFault is false

>>>> After moving object back to fault, isFault is true
```

Seems to achieve our goal

1. Read `lite_title` will not trigger SQLite DB operation.
2. Read `heavy_body` will trigger SQLite DB operation.

However, we aren't sure after `note.managedObjectContext?.refresh(note, mergeChanges: false)`, is `heavy_body` discarded from the memory? Even though `isFault` is returning true, we can only confirm such by running the same function for the 2nd time

---

### 2nd Attempt doesn't work

We run the same function for the 2nd time. This is our logging

```
>>>> This is a fault.

>>>> Read lite_title

>>>> After accessing lite_title, isFault is false

>>>> Read heavy_body

>>>> After accessing heavy_body, isFault is false

>>>> After moving object back to fault, isFault is true
```

Although `isFault` is true, but no SQLite DB operation observed, when we read `heavy_body`. It looks like, `heavy_body` is still staying in the memory cache of CoreData!

---

We would like to remove `heavy_body` from the memory, and leave `lite_title` untouched for this case.

Or, even if `lite_title` is removed from memory, when accessing `note.lite_title` and triggering fault firing, only `lite_title` should be SQLite fetched (As stated in `propertiesToFetch`, we onyl want `lite_title` to be fetched). `heavy_body` should NOT be SQLite fetched along the side.

May I know, how I can achieve so?

The complete sample code to demonstrate the issue is at https://github.com/yccheok/faulting-example

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html (Turning object back to fault)

---

### Update regarding turning off caching mechanism in CoreData

Based on suggestion from @Eugene Dudnyk, I was able to turn off the caching mechanism of CoreData by using

```
container.viewContext.stalenessInterval = 0.1
```

With such code, I am able to observe SQLite fetch in 2nd attempt.

```
>>>> This is a fault.

>>>> Read lite_title

CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZHEAVY_BODY, t0.ZLITE_TITLE, t0.ZUUID FROM ZNOTE t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)1
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0002s
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x600002b80320> on entity 'Note' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZHEAVY_BODY, t0.ZLITE_TITLE, t0.ZUUID FROM ZNOTE t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? ' returned 1 rows
CoreData: annotation:  with values: (
    "<NSSQLRow: 0x6000006991a0>{Note 1-1-6 heavy_body=\"the body, which is a heavy resource\" lite_title=\"the title\" uuid=F80CE382-0345-49A0-AD34-2BAF317AB0C0 and to-manys=0x0}"
)
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x9aff7ac6eceb6a90 <x-coredata://DBF3953E-6ABA-4542-9F79-89822F537A93/Note/p1> with row values: <NSSQLRow: 0x6000006991a0>{Note 1-1-6 heavy_body="the body, which is a heavy resource" lite_title="the title" uuid=F80CE382-0345-49A0-AD34-2BAF317AB0C0 and to-manys=0x0}
>>>> After accessing lite_title, isFault is false

>>>> Read heavy_body

>>>> After accessing heavy_body, isFault is false

>>>> After moving object back to fault, isFault is true
```

However, there is still a pitfall.

When reading `lite_title`, I was expecting SQLite data fetching will respect `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch`, by only fetching `lite_title`.

However, it seems that SQLite data is fetching the entire `Note` object, by fetching `heavy_body` as well.

How can I avoid from fetching `heavy_body`, if I am only interested in `lite_title`?

Thanks.

Comment: One workaround is to place heavy_body in a separate entity with a 1:1 relationship to your Note.  The original fetch will by default include only the lite_title (relationships remain faults until triggered), and you can refresh the separate object to flush it from memory without affecting the Note object.

Comment: I recommend to ask yourself again why you have to fetch thousands of entries to display in a UICollectionView. You could improve performance by adding lazy loading of more elements when your user scrolls down.
Also, is heavy_body something you want to store in CoreData?

Answer (score 1):

CoreData has underlying caching. `ManagedObjectContext` has a property `stalenessInterval` to control for how long the cached informtation should be considered fresh. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506875-stalenessinterval).

The default value of the property defines infinite staleness.

To test that it makes a difference, add to `CoreDataStack.swift:30` this line:

```
container.viewContext.stalenessInterval = 0.1
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the issue. But it provides a useful info on how to debug such issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all of this additional work can be avoided if `Note` stores the `heavy_body` text into a file separately and it needs to know that `filePath` only.

Whenever app needs to load the full `heavy_body`, (say opening a `Note` details screen), read/load the contents of the file located at `Note.filePath`.

As soon as you are done dealing with the `heavy_body`, move away from the `Note` details screen and system takes care of cleaning that up automatically.

---

In case you want to show some metadata about the `heavy_body` in the `UICollectionViewCell` itself, (say size/length), you could store additional metadata on the `Note` object and keep it in sync with `heavy_body` data by setting/updating appropriate values in the [`willSave()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506209-willsave) callback.

---

CoreData manages it's caching for valid reasons and fighting it to make it work for this case might create more bookkeeping work than necessary.